# Removing mssql-server from Ubuntu 20.04 in WSL1

Tags: apt, 20.04, xubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I installed mssql-server on Ubuntu 20.04 running as WSL1. However that turns out to be a bad move as it can't get it installed properly.
To makes things worse, I can't remove it either. So my apt stuck with mssql-server that I can neither install properly nor completely remove.

When I try to remove it, it will show the error like below

```
root@my-host:/var/cache/apt# apt remove mssql-server
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libc++1 libc++1-10 libc++abi1-10 libsss-nss-idmap0
Use 'apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  mssql-server
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 139 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 1195 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
dpkg: error processing package mssql-server (--remove):
 package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
 reinstall it before attempting a removal
dpkg: too many errors, stopping
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mssql-server
Processing was halted because there were too many errors.
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try this once "sudo mv /var/lib/dpkg/info/mssql-server.* /tmp/" then "
sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq mssql-server"

Comment: @zabiullah awesome!!! It works... If you can make your comment as an answer, I'd accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this `sudo mv /var/lib/dpkg/info/mssql-server.* /tmp/` then `sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq mssql-server`

Comment: The first command will cause some serious problems. **-1**. The correct solution is to run `sudo dpkg -P mssql-server`

Comment: Yah this worked, had a half baked install on my wsl2 system where the stupid mssql package wanted to stop the service with "systemd" resulting in "System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.". So good riddance :)